# Dividing value of polygon in polygon inside it

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, population

I'm working with population data. I want to divide the population value (labeled in the orange square)in the polygons inside it (blue polygons).

[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want to do when a blue polygon is under two or more orange squares?

Comment: Yes , the precision doesn't matter a lot , if the blue polygon is under muliple orange squares we will asign it the value according the biggest part of it

Comment: Is this what you want to do? For each orange square, work out the total area of blue houses within it. Then for each blue square within that orange square, work out the proportion of its individual area to the total blue area within that orange boundary. Then assign to that individual house the proportion of the orange population according to the proportion of the area of that house to the total of houses in that orange square.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clip the GRID polygons with the buildings
2. Make Feature layer on grid with `Use ratio policy` on value field:
   [image]
3. Intersect the created layer and the houses